# List View sometimes do not show data from my DataSource.cs

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, async-await

I am newbie in WinRT developing. I'm triing to bind data from my datasource to ListView. But there is problem when I use

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("tasks.xml");
var readStream = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

if I use this code then application sometimes don't show that data in ListView (it is really random, sometimes it show everything OK and sometimes don't show anything in ListView).

When I delete this code from datasource then everithing works well.

I have this datasource class (DataSource.cs)

```
public class InboxPageViewModel
{
    public List<Task> Items { get; set; }

    public InboxPageViewModel()
    {
        GetTasks();
    }

    private async void GetTasks()
    {
        try
        {
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("tasks.xml");
            var readStream = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

            var tasksList = new List<Task>
            {
                new Task { Name = "a", DueDate = "b", Project = "c", Context = "d"},
            };

            Items = tasksList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new MessageDialog(ex.Message).ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}

public class Task
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string DueDate { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string Context { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string IsFinished { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use `async void` methods (unless you're writing an event handler).

And you also shouldn't call `async` methods from constructors, for more information read [Stephen Cleary's article about that](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, it's wery helpfull, but how can I acces storage file without FileIO.ReadTextAsync?

Comment: @user1128073 I didn't say you shouldn't use that.

Comment: I'm little bit confused :) I try some code changes from article what you send in your post, but problem is still here. I probably do something wrong. Can you give me a sample how should my data source code look?

Comment: @user1128073: In my article I describe a few approaches for "async constructors". In your case I'd recommend the async factory if possible, otherwise the async Initialization. Note that if you asynchronously update your Items property, then you'll have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for that property.

Comment: Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged solve my problem, thank you.

Comment: Just adding a note that the answer to this question really is in implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. Your GetTasks method is completely fine without returning a Task if you are only calling it from a constructor and handling all exceptions. I would just recommend calling it GetTasksAsync to make it double clear that it is in fact async.

Comment: @FilipSkakun I think it's not a good idea. A constructor should return fully constructed object, not one that will be constructed some time in the future, if you're lucky.

Comment: That sounds like a nice ideal to shoot for, but not realistic with view models. When you create a view you often wire up your view model through XAML and you can't wait for an instance to be created. View models are often in constant flux and never fully populated.